# Elements different position in Chrome and Firefox with css reset

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, positioning

Again I'm encountering a problem while making my protfolio page.
I made my code while checking in Firefox - so now my website looks good in that but it differs in Chrome - though only at very few parts.
I'll add some pictures so you can see, what differs:
[This is how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kjTw.png) but 
[this is how it looks in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvMpK.png)
I have a similar problem in the footer as well.

I already used a css reset and searched through my code but I just can't seem to find the mistake?
It's like there are suddenly more margins, so that Chrome moves the elements.

Here is the html code for the navbar:

```
<!--Nav-->
    <nav>
        <div class="nav-links">
            <a href="#start"><img src="images/Bildmarke.svg" alt="home"></a>
            <p>lisa röhl</p>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-rechts">
            <ul id="nav-ul">
                <li><a class="nav" id="nav-work" href="#work">work</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav" id="nav-skills" href="#skills">skills</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav" id="nav-about" href="#about">about</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav" id="nav-contact" href="#contact">contact</a></li>            

            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

and the css part:
default:

```
/*NAV*/
nav{
    height:10vh;
    position: relative;
    z-index:9000;
    background-color:#e4e0da;
    width:100%;
    clear:both;
}
.nav{
    text-decoration:none !important;
    color:#2b3534 !important;
    font-size:4vh;
}
.nav-links{
    float:left;
}
.nav-links p{
    display:none;
    position: relative;
}
.nav-links img{
    width:15vh;
    margin-top:10%;
    margin-left:2%;
}
.nav-rechts{
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    position: absolute;
}
.nav-rechts ul, li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display:table;
    padding:auto;
}
.nav-rechts li{
    margin-left:3vw;
    float:left;
}
#nav-ul{
    margin-right: 5%;
    bottom:0;
    margin-bottom:0 !important;
}

.nav-hover{
    color:#e76600 !important;
}
.main-nav-scrolled{
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;

}
```

and tablet modification:

```
.nav{
    color:#2b3534 !important;
    font-size:3vh;
}
.sticky-nav ul{
    margin: 4.5% 1% 0 0;
}
.nav-hover{
    color:#e76600 !important;
}
```

and desktop:

```
.nav{
    font-size:3.5vh;
}
.nav-links p{
    font-size:5vh;
    color:#2b3534;
    display:inline-block;   
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0 !important;
    margin-bottom:0 !important;
}
.nav:hover{
    color:#e76600 !important;
}
```

if you need the code for the footer, too, please say so - I guess they both have the same mistake.
And please note, that I haven't doublechecked the breackpoints for now, so there might be still things that double ^^'

Comment: could you add your code in fiddle...

Comment: sorry, I'm actually not used to fiddle...I tried but it won't look like on my page: [link](http://codepen.io/l0ttch3n/pen/zBazEX)
my whole site would be too much (cause of img and such)
i thought these code parts would be enough?
i also already set the margin and padding on body to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I now found the problem:
Chrome seems to have a problem with floating and a set margin.
So I just changed this part:

```
#nav-ul{
margin-right: 5%;
bottom:0;
margin-bottom:0 !important;
```

}

to this:

```
#nav-ul{
    right: 5%;
    bottom:0;
    margin-bottom:0 !important;
}
```

So basically just changing from margin-right to just right (since I'm positioning absolute).